# How to remind every 2 hours at specific time intervals using flutter

Tags: flutter, reminders, flutter-local-notification, awesome-notifications

I am writing a water reminder application. I want to send a notification every 2 hours at specific time intervals by using flutter_local_notifications or awesome_notifications. Its notifications should be sent every 2 hours, starting at 8 AM and ending at 6 PM or at a specified start and end time. Is there a way to do these operations?

Comment: I think this answer will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/71171816/8544376

Answer (score 0):

you can use a package like cron https://pub.dev/packages/cron to achieve this.

```
 cron.schedule(Schedule.parse('*/3 * * * *'), () async {
    print('every three minutes');
  });
```