# Flutte local notification at a specific time daily for android

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-local-notification

[android only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvDFp.png)

I tried **NotificationServices** Scheduled method with **_flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.periodicallyShow** and it doesn't seems to work.

also **how to test it in a android emulator** (changing the date and time on the device works or not)

## notification_service.dart

```
class NotificationServices {
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  final AndroidInitializationSettings _androidInitializationSettings =
      AndroidInitializationSettings('logo1');

  void initialiseNotifications() async {
    InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: _androidInitializationSettings,
    );

    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
  }

  void scheduleNotifications(String title, String body) async {
    int hour = 19;
    var ogValue = hour;
    int minute = 05;
    var time = Time(hour,minute,20);

    AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
    const AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'channelId',
      'channelName',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
    );

    NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidNotificationDetails,
    );

    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.periodicallyShow(
        0, 'title', 'body', RepeatInterval.daily, notificationDetails);
  }

  void stopNotifications() async{
    _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(0);
  }

}
```

## main.dart

```
NotificationServices notificationServices = NotificationServices();

  notificationServices.initialiseNotifications();
  notificationServices.scheduleNotifications('Daily Reminder', 'You have a ToDo list to complete');
```

Comment: May be you should refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71171816/8544376

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem myself.
Referenced the code below who is looking for the answer

```
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:flutter_native_timezone/flutter_native_timezone.dart';
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;

class NotificationHelper {
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  /// Initialize notification
  initializeNotification() async {
    _configureLocalTimeZone();
    const IOSInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings();

    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings("ic_launcher");

    const InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
    );
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
  }

  /// Set right date and time for notifications
  tz.TZDateTime _convertTime(int hour, int minutes) {
    final tz.TZDateTime now = tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local);
    tz.TZDateTime scheduleDate = tz.TZDateTime(
      tz.local,
      now.year,
      now.month,
      now.day,
      hour,
      minutes,
    );
    if (scheduleDate.isBefore(now)) {
      scheduleDate = scheduleDate.add(const Duration(days: 1));
    }
    return scheduleDate;
  }

  Future<void> _configureLocalTimeZone() async {
    tz.initializeTimeZones();
    final String timeZone = await FlutterNativeTimezone.getLocalTimezone();
    tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation(timeZone));
  }

  /// Scheduled Notification
  scheduledNotification({
    required int hour,
    required int minutes,
    required int id,
    required String sound,
  }) async {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
      id,
      'It\'s time to drink water!',
      'After drinking, touch the cup to confirm',
      _convertTime(hour, minutes),
      NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          'your channel id $sound',
          'your channel name',
          channelDescription: 'your channel description',
          importance: Importance.max,
          priority: Priority.high,
          sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound(sound),
        ),
        iOS: IOSNotificationDetails(sound: '$sound.mp3'),
      ),
      androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation: UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
      matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.time,
      payload: 'It could be anything you pass',
    );
  }

  /// Request IOS permissions
  void requestIOSPermissions() {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.requestPermissions(
          alert: true,
          badge: true,
          sound: true,
        );
  }

  cancelAll() async => await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancelAll();
  cancel(id) async => await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(id);
}
```

Comment: You've copied the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/71171816/8544376 and mentioned with your name. Instead you should give the credit to the original answer.