# flutter local notifications not showing

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification

In my application I am trying to show a daily reminder to use the app.
I am using flutter local notifications.
When i use the show() method it works as expected.
However when i try to schedule it using zonedSchedule() i see no notifications (on actual device or emulator).
Currently I expect both notifications to show just after startup while the app is still in the foreground.

I use the following function to init the time zone prior to calling the show

```
Future<void> _configureLocalTimeZone() async {
  tz.initializeTimeZones();
  final String timeZoneName = await FlutterTimezone.getLocalTimezone();
  tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation(timeZoneName));
}
```

Schedule notification function:

```
Future<void> _scheduleNotification() async {
  int id = Random().nextInt(10000);
  const notificationDetails = AndroidNotificationDetails('Channel ID', 'Channel name',
                                channelDescription: 'Channels description');
  // The following show works
//  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(id, 'title', 'body', 
//                                              const NotificationDetails(
//                                                android: notificationDetails));

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
      id,
      'Title',
      "body",
      tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(const Duration(seconds: 5)),
      const NotificationDetails(
          android: notificationDetails),
      androidScheduleMode: AndroidScheduleMode.exactAllowWhileIdle,
      androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
      matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.time,
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
          UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime);
}
```

Following are the permissions for android:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
```

Comment: You might take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71171816/13432825